# Deleting ':' in a value

Tags: python, string, list

I have this value:

```
y = c0:ad:0c:5a:f4:42:89:41:c5:6c:d7:48:8b:91:a2:f6:34:9c
```

I want to delete all of the ':' characters.
I have tried different ways, such as lists, without success.

Could anyone help me?

(Sorry for my English)

Comment: Please post WHAT DID NOT work that you tried so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Directly from the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace

Answer (score 8):

Just use [`y.replace(':', '')`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
In [13]: y = 'c0:ad:0c:5a:f4:42:89:41:c5:6c:d7:48:8b:91:a2:f6:34:9c'

In [14]: y.replace(':', '')
Out[14]: 'c0ad0c5af4428941c56cd7488b91a2f6349c'
```

Comment: translate is [faster](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14606111/748858) ;-)

Comment: @mgilson: Yep, just tested it too. About 18% faster here.

Comment: any idea why that is the case?

Comment: @isedev -- I hint at it in my post.  `str.replace` needs to be able to handle substrings of arbitrary length, so that leads to a little extra checking I would assume.  Also, it needs to handle the case where you're replacing a string with a bigger string which means that there's no way to know a-priori how much memory you'll need to hold your string.  With `translate`, you know that the result is always going to be the same length or shorter which might allow for some optimization.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate):

```
y = "c0:ad:0c:5a:f4:42:89:41:c5:6c:d7:48:8b:91:a2:f6:34:9c"
y.translate(None,':')
```

It's fast :-)

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def replace(x):
...     return x.replace(":","")
... 
>>> def translate(x):
...     return x.translate(None,':')
... 
>>> y = "c0:ad:0c:5a:f4:42:89:41:c5:6c:d7:48:8b:91:a2:f6:34:9c"
>>> replace(y) == translate(y)
True
>>> timeit.timeit('replace(y)','from __main__ import replace,y')
1.3739330768585205
>>> timeit.timeit('translate(y)','from __main__ import translate,y')
0.9205348491668701
```

It also scales up to allow the deletion of *multiple* characters, but it doesn't do substrings.  For example, you can remove words with `str.replace`, but you can't easily/efficiently remove `'x'` or `'y'` or `'z'`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try splitting and rejoining the string. Also, there are ways using Regex, but that is probably overkill.

```
y = "c0:ad:0c:5a:f4:42:89:41:c5:6c:d7:48:8b:91:a2:f6:34:9c"

print("".join(y.split(sep=":")))
```

Answer (score 0):

One more possibility(just in case you need list of values from the original value) to do this using [string.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [string.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is:

```
y = c0:ad:0c:5a:f4:42:89:41:c5:6c:d7:48:8b:91:a2:f6:34:9c
y = ''.join(y.split(':'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python guy, but I would use replace().
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

```
y = "c0:ad:0c:5a:f4:42:89:41:c5:6c:d7:48:8b:91:a2:f6:34:9c";
y.replace(":","");
```

Comment: I am a python guy -- And I might use `replace` for this.  I also might use `translate`, but I'd definitely remove the trailing semicolons ;-P

Answer (score 0):

and why not

```
print ''.join([x for x in y if x!=":"])
```

different solutions for different approach. Maybe this solution can do some other things not in question.